# Using F# portable class library from C# portable library

Tags: c#, xamarin, f#, visual-studio-2015

I have a WPF application that uses a F# library for calculations. I'm trying to refactor so that I have WPF Application -> C# Portable Class Library (models) -> F# Portable Class Library (calculations).

My end goal is to use Xamarin Forms to put a UI on it that I can use on other platforms. This is currently mostly an experiment to assess the viability of the approach.

Every time I try to add a reference to the F# library from the C# library, I get an error message that says "Unable to add reference to X, Portable class libraries can only reference other portable class libraries".

I can reference either library from the WPF project and I've tried every permutation that I can think of to make it work.

There are quite a few similar questions, but they either don't have an answer or state that it is fixed in VS 2013. It doesn't seem to work in VS 2015 Update 2.

Does anyone have a link to a sample that works, or a workaround to get past the problem?

Comment: Did you try to make the F# library portable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps for VS 2015 Update 2:

1. Create new(tested with new solution) Class Library (Portable)
2. As target choose **only** Windows 10 or Windows 8.1(maybe other target would work too - haven't tested though)
3. Add F# Portable Library(tested with .Net 4.5, Windows Store, Xamarin
   and with .Net 4.5, Windows Store, Silverlight 5, Xamarin)
4. Now you can reference F# library without any errors
5. Now You can change properties of C# project(Right click on c# project and
   choose properties) to match the targets You would like to have (Section Library, subsection Targeting)

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work. It required me to install the Windows 8.1 libraries, but after that I could create the C# project and add a reference to my existing F# PCL. Hopefully, they'll eventually fix VS so it works without requiring workarounds.